Is $\int_{0}^{n} {x \choose n+1} dx = 0$ true?
Is the equation below true when $x \choose n+1$ is defined?
$$\int_{0}^{n} {x \choose n+1} dx = 0$$
In the MIT Integration Bee ($2023$), $$\int_0^4 {x \choose 5}dx = 0$$
so $\int_{0}^{n} {x \choose n+1} dx = 0$ might be true.
MY ATTEMPT:
We can re-write $$\int_{0}^{n} {x \choose n+1} dx = 0$$
as $$\int_{0}^{n} {\frac{x!}{(n+1)!(x-n+1)!}} dx = 0$$
I tried using the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to continue but $\frac{d}{dx}x!$ contains the gamma function and digamma function which is too complicated. See here.
So is the equation below true when $x \choose n+1$ is defined?
$$\int_{0}^{n} {x \choose n+1} dx = 0$$

WA gave no answer

$\binom{a}{b}$ is usually defined to be $0$ , if $a<b$.

The graph of $x \choose 5$ has reflective symmetry about $(2, 0)$ over a symmetric interval so this might be true generally.

It depends on whether $n$ is even or odd ...

Don't use $x!$ notation when $x$ is real. The numerator is a polynomial of degree $n+1.$

@ThomasAndrews do I use falling factorial instead as JMoravitz said?

You can use whatever notation you want, but $x!$ is only defined for integers $x\geq0,$ not nor non-integers, so you'd have to write $\Gamma(x+1).$ But the gamma function is a big honking mess for this problem, since, ultimately, the integrand is a polynomial. Falling factorial is good enough.

If we interpret the integral as $$I_n:=\int_0^n \frac{x(x-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (x-n)}{(n+1)!} \,\text{d}x $$ then $I_n$ is $0$ iff $n$ is even.
Indeed, when $n$ is even the change of variable $y=n-x\Rightarrow\text{d}y=-\text{d}x$ gives \begin{align*} I_n &= -\int_n^0 \frac{(n-y)(n-1-y)\cdot \ldots \cdot (-y)}{(n+1)!} \,\text{d}y \\ &=\int_0^n (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{y(y-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (y-n)}{(n+1)!} \,\text{d}y \\ &=-I_n\end{align*} as we are taking a product of $n+1$ terms, thus $I_n=0$.
On the other hand, if $n$ is odd it can be shown that $I_n<0$.

So can I write the integral as I did in my question or should I write it how you did?

Too long for comment:
To be clear, the binomial coefficient is most often defined only for situations with non-negative integers as both the top and the bottom arguments and answers counting questions about how many subsets there are of a certain size.  Similarly, factorials are often only defined for situations with non-negative integers... again answering counting questions.
In this original interpretation of binomial coefficients (and only in this case) do we have $\binom{a}{b} = \dfrac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$.  This identity (or definition depending) makes no sense when dealing with non-negative integers.
One can talk about the extended binomial coefficient, where this allows any type of number for the first argument but still requires the second argument be a non-negative integer.  The definition in such a case would be that $\binom{a}{b} = \dfrac{a^{\underline{b}}}{b!}$ where here we use the notation for the falling factorial that $a^{\underline{b}} = \prod\limits_{i=0}^{b-1}(a-i) = \underbrace{a(a-1)(a-2)\cdots(a-b+1)}_{b\text{ terms}}$
In such a case, we can now make sense of the integral... this is very simply going to be $\int\limits_{0}^4 \dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}{5!}dx$ in the specific case of the MIT bee, and $\int\limits_{0}^n \dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)}{(n+1)!}dx$ in your main question.
In either event, you will have a polynomial of degree $n+1$ which you can consider if there is symmetry involved over the domain.
One can see in certain choices of $n$ however that this is nonzero (as alluded to in the comments) such as how $\int\limits_{0}^1x(x-1)dx = -\frac{1}{6}\neq 0$

"To be clear, the binomial coefficient is most often defined only for situations with non-negative integers as both the top and the bottom arguments" This isn't true - we use the notation $\binom xn$ for real $x$ quite a lot. The lower number is a positive integer in this notation.

@ThomasAndrews the lower number being zero would amount to an empty product divided by $0!$ and would thus equal $1$.  Are you suggesting otherwise?  As for the bit about "most often..." it is (as with everything) highly context specific.  Of course, certain disciplines will almost exclusively use one over the other, but for the ley ordinary student mathematician I would strongly suspect they would only be introduced to the combinatorial meaning.

No, a fundamental theorem is the generalized binomial theorem, and I dare you to find any version of it that does not write it as: $$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom \alpha n x^n$$ for $|x|<1.$ It is usual to first encounter with the top and bottom non-negative integers, but it is established notation what is meant when the top number is real. (And yes, I should have said $n$ is non-negative....)

thanks everyone
